# can i .htaccess rewrite an url to subfolder if it is one of two alias domains?

Tags: .htaccess

two domains point on one and the same webapplication on my server.
but when I use the http://domainA.tld it shall point to http://domainB.tld/service but it shall not be a riderict and the address bar should have the `domainA.tld`.

from that point on, I want to work normally on the system always holding the A-domain also in formular submits and url links, etc.

I am really stuck here. This is what i Tried

```
# the block i need for my MVC Architecture
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/favicon\.ico [NC]
RewriteRule . index.php

# service rewrite
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domainB.tld/service/
```

Comment: please comment why -1, like it is common.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by my selfe:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ippservice\.kommt\-bald\.at$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ service [R]
```